# Jenkins does not find codesigning problems

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

I've spent the whole day trying to understand whats happening here but without any luck. Basically what I wanna do is configure jenkins with Xcode plugin to build an iOS project. Everything is installed and working, the projects builds correctly without a problem, but jenkins seems to not like it at all.

I'm using the Xcode Plugin available on Jenkins. And the build process seems to not find any valid identities so in the end the build fails because it cannot sign.

```
$ /usr/bin/security find-identity -p codesigning -v
     0 valid identities found
```

If I run the same command on the terminal It does find all the valid identities, and jenkins is running on that same user! I've also tried manually adding the keychain and unlocking the keychain prior to the Xcode build but no luck also.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Where did you run the "code" you posted? In a Jenkins bash section? Could you post the error message from the Jenkins log, or provide any other additional information which might be helpful?

Comment: Hey Man, thank you for the help.I did not run that "code" It's the output of the jenkins console. And the error at the end of the build process is basically saying It couldn't find a valid certificate to sign the app. And that is verified by that "code" :)

Comment: Did you check, if it'll find your identities, when running this line in a terminal window manually?

Comment: Yeah, it does :)

Comment: And you are sure its the same user, maybe you can add a `whoami` to verify that?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure, I also verified with whoami :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138976/discussion-between-d4rk-and-diogo-antunes).